# Merging files, with certain text in filename; from a folder directory into a single Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder directory with several Excel files. I have written code that copies every file in that directory to a single Excel worksheet.

This folder has a few different categories of files.

I need to add a condition that states the file must contain "Marios" in the filename.

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub grabdata()
    Dim FSO         As Object
    Dim fsoFol      As Object
    Dim fsoFile     As Object
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim wksSource   As Worksheet

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fsoFol = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Desktop" & "\")
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFol.Files
        If fsoFile.Type Like "Microsoft*Excel*Work*" _
          And Not fsoFile.Path = ThisWorkbook.FullName Then

            On Error GoTo 10

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fsoFile.Path, False, True)
            Set wksSource = Nothing

            On Error Resume Next

            Set wksSource = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
            
            If Not wksSource Is Nothing Then
                wksSource.Range("A1:i100").Copy _
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nintendo").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
            
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            wb.Close False
        End If
    Next
10
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `InStr` or `Like` to test if the filename contains the word.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the check to your If statement.

```
If fsoFile.Type Like "Microsoft*Excel*Work*" _
   And Not fsoFile.Path = ThisWorkbook.FullName _
   And fsoFile.Name Like "Marios*" Then
```